# Миллисекунды в дату на JS

Tags: node.js, javascript

Есть ли штатные функции для перевода миллисекунд UNIX времени в год/месяц/день/час/мин и т.д. ???

Comment: [Date][1]
[1]:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @zhenyab, раз уж у нас русскоязычный форум, то ссылку можно давать на [русский язык][1]

[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @MasterAlex, а я и не знал, что есть русский :) И никогда не интересовался, есть ли русский перевод

Comment: ну то, что Date я уже понял, и там полно примеров, как получить из даты мс, а вот обратно сложнее. Я беру 

    var x = Date(milisec);

и получаю Wed Mar 18 2015 17:25:12 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (лето)), а как потом из этого получить нормальные числовые представления?

Пробовал 

    x.getDate()

или сразу
 
    var x = Date(milisec).getDate();

но так не работает, прошу сильно не пинать, ибо JS я пока только начал глубоко изучать.

Comment: @vnn198 потому что ты неправильно пользуешься инструментом

    var month = (new Date()).getMonth() + 1;

поэтому пиши так, как рекомендуют в примерах, пока ты не научился чему-то большему

    var date = new Date();
    var mont = date.getMonth() + 1;


да, и вот ещё что: раз у тебя нода, то нет никакого смысла ограничивать себя "штатными" функциями, бери http://momentjs.com/ и делай с датами всё, что заблагорассудится.

Comment: Я предчувствовал упоминание moment.js в этом вопросе :)

Comment: @Lucky, куда ж без него :)

Comment: Да мне сложно начится потому что мало информации на русском чтобы мне учится, мне для того чтобы понять нужно знать как работает компилятор при встрече определённого оператора, а везде обычно объясняют по другому, собственно поэтому такие штуки как new this и т.д. были мне мало понятны, с this вроде разобрался более менее, с new пока не до конца

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@vnn198](/users/26807/vnn198) потому что ты неправильно пользуешься инструментом

```
var month = (new Date()).getMonth() + 1;
```

поэтому пиши так, как рекомендуют в примерах, пока ты не научился чему-то большему

```
var date = new Date();
var mont = date.getMonth() + 1;
```

да, и вот ещё что: раз у тебя нода, то нет никакого смысла ограничивать себя "штатными" функциями, бери http://momentjs.com/ и делай с датами всё, что заблагорассудится.

Answer (score 1):

Штатные есть, уже ответили.
Я оставлю ссылку на библиотеку [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/). Очень удобно манипулировать датами и временем с ее помощью

Answer (score 0):

Что есть нормальные числовые представления? Date имеет такие методы, как getDate(), getDay(), getFullYear() и т.д., там по ссылке, данной выше, про них можно почитать, если вы об этом.

Comment: Проблема в том что я их неправильно вызыывл, теперь вроде разобрался